# Странный ответ от сервера при парсинге

Tags: python, http, requests, lxml

хочу спарсить расписание.
расписание подгружается через запрос post.

```
import requests
import time
import lxml.html
import datetime


headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
               'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
               'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive',
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}

urls_main = "https://lk.ugatu.su/raspisanie/#timetable"


#метод преобзования ответа от сервера в дерево DOM
def get_html (request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request, 'html.parser')

#Метод для вывода html, только для этапа разработки
def print_html(html):
    print(lxml.html.tostring(html, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))

def get_token(html):
    return html.cssselect('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]')[0].get("value")



def get_items_value_options(block):
    items = []
    options = block.cssselect('option[value!=""]')
    for option in options:
        value = option.get("value")
        items.append(value)
    return items

def parse_schedule(params, session):
    global headers
    r = session.post("https://lk.ugatu.su/raspisanie/", data=params, headers=headers).content
    html = get_html(r)
    # print_html(html)
    try:
        token = get_token(html)

    except:
        #Выкинуло 403 ошибку
        exit(-10)

    # schedule_block = html.cssselect("#schedule")[0]
    # print_html(schedule_block)
    print_html(html)
    time.sleep(100)




    return [token, session]

def parse_main(url_old):
    global headers

    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get(url_old, headers=headers).content
    html = get_html(r)

    token = get_token(html)
    print(token)
    # Блок нахождения списка курсов
    groups = get_items_value_options(html.cssselect("#id_group")[0])

    weeks = get_items_value_options(html.cssselect("#WeekSchedule")[0])

    semesters = get_items_value_options(html.cssselect("#SemestrSchedule")[0])

    #Обновляем headers
    headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
               'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
               'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive',
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0',
               'Referer': "https://lk.ugatu.su/raspisanie/",
               'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': str(1),
               'Host': 'lk.ugatu.su'}
    type = "За+неделю"
    url_new = "https://lk.ugatu.su/raspisanie/"
    count = 0
    for semester in semesters:
        for week in weeks:
            for group in groups:
                # print([semester, week, group, type])
                count += 1
                date = f"{datetime.datetime.now():%d.%m.%Y}"
                #Параметры для будущего Post Запроса
                params = {
                    "group" : group,
                    "ScheduleType": type,
                    "sem" : semester,
                    "week": week,
                    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": token,
                    "view": "Показать",
                    "faculty": "",
                    "klass": "",
                    "date": date

                }

                request_params = parse_schedule(params, session)
                token = request_params[0]
                session = request_params[1]
                #Пока прервемся, так как все равно не можем выполнить первый Post запрос
                # break




if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()

    urls_params = parse_main(urls_main)


    print("Время работы парсера:", time.time() - start_time)
```

Проблема в том, что не видно table элемента, где находится расписание. Хотя в полезной нагрузки у Post-запроса через браузер он виден.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, если бы javascript пришел, тогда да, но пришел же Html. Почему так происходит? Или какой-то из скриптов скрывает элемент?

Comment: А попробуйте сохранить ту html и открыть ее браузером, там должен быть результат, например "Ошибка проверки CSRF. Запрос отклонён."

Comment: @gil9red, который в браузере в полезной нагрузке? или который я получил в pYthon

Comment: @gil9red в браузере то в ответе он виден

Comment: @gil9red скопировал из полезной нагрузки и сохранил в Html, table видна

Comment: Конечно, то, что вы получили из скрипта :) Мне кое-что удалось сделать по этому парсеру, но на POST возвращает тоже самое, что и для GET. Зато уже не 403 ошибка

Comment: @gil9red, там нету

Comment: @gil9red посмотрел через request.text и request.content, это блока там нету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD.**

Проблема оказалась в кодировании FORM-данных при наличии в значении символа `+`, например для строки `'За+неделю'` браузер кодировал как `%D0%97%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E`, а `requests` как `%D0%97%D0%B0%2B%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E`.

---

Пришлось повозиться с этим сайтом, смотреть через Инструмент разработчика в браузере какие запросы посылает браузер, с каким куками, что приходит в ответ.

Так же воспользовался `requests.Session` чтобы тот обрабатывал заголовки ответов с куками от сервера и сам при запросе на сервер добавлял куки к нему.

Кст, мне **очень** помог [просмотр логов `requests`](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/fc39378cf1b3b0fa3a067166a0e54423d36a3b98/requests_example/debug_logging__requests.py) -- чтобы видно было что тот отправляет

[Код](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c0dd11a0a53d2dafe0ccf2d8e6bf82f2227961bc/html_parsing/https__lk_ugatu_su_raspisanie/main.py):

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_csrfmiddlewaretoken(rs) -> str:
    match = re.search("csrfmiddlewaretoken: '(.+?)',", rs.text)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)


COMMON_HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0',
}


with requests.Session() as s:
    rs = s.get('https://lk.ugatu.su/raspisanie/', headers=COMMON_HEADERS)
    print(rs)

    csrfmiddlewaretoken = get_csrfmiddlewaretoken(rs)

    # Эмуляция клика на кнопку "ПОКАЗАТЬ"
    data = {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrfmiddlewaretoken,
        'faculty': 'АВИЭТ',
        'klass': '1',
        'group': '2435',
        'ScheduleType': 'За+неделю',
        'week': '5',
        'date': '07.03.2019',
        'sem': '9',
        'view': 'ПОКАЗАТЬ',
    }
    # Костыль для обхода проблемы составления ScheduleType='За+неделю'
    # Дело в том, что если в data положить словарь, то 'За+неделю' будет закодирован как
    # '%D0%97%D0%B0%2B%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E'
    # а браузер кодирует как '%D0%97%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E', т.е.
    # символ '+' должен оставаться собой. Если плюс закодировать, сервер вернет пустую таблицу
    #
    # NOTE: возможно, лучше вместо костыля с urlencode+replace вручную собрать строку
    #
    data = urlencode(data).replace('%2B', '+').encode()

    headers = {
        'Referer': "https://lk.ugatu.su/raspisanie/",

        # Нужно заполнить, т.к. в post data передан не как словарь
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    headers.update(COMMON_HEADERS)

    rs = s.post('https://lk.ugatu.su/raspisanie/', data=data, headers=headers)

    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
    print(root.select_one('#schedule .bgc-lecture-practical'))
```

Консоль:

```
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
<td class="bgc-lecture-practical"><p><font class="font-subject">Современные проблемы биомедицинской и экологической инженерии</font><br/><font class="font-classroom"><a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(1, 3, 128)">4-324</a></font><font class="font-teacher"><p>Лекция + практика</p><a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(1, 2, 50126)">Демин Алексей Юрьевич</a></font></p></td>
```

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема была? В кодировании +?

Comment: @danilshik, ваша -- хз, вы могли не заполнить правильно csrfmiddlewaretoken или вообще не заполнить, или не получить кук sessionid, или не заполнить Referer :) Но скорее всего в том `+`. Кст, проверил код без того ajax -- тоже проходит, так что убрал его

Comment: ну для post Запроса я указал referer, csrfmiddlewaretoken я получал из Input, при нажатии на показать в параметрах уходил точно такое же значение как и у input, чтобы сессия была, я специально Session использовал (он же куки сохраняет, так ведь)

Comment: @danilshik, значит попробуйте мой вариант с urlencode+replace и в headers добавьте `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, думаю, тогда сработает

Comment: проблема была в символе +, покрайней мере этот блок возвращается с надписью нет расписания)

Comment: @danilshik, мда, без просмотра логов requests фиг бы смог догадаться в чем проблема, удачи :)

Comment: спасибо большое